# ros2_control/asio : topics stops being received

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having issues with a ros2_control on humble distro and ubuntu 22.04. I have a custom hardware system that communicates with the hardware with TCP/IP. I implemented the communication using asio, running in a thread. I am using a custom controller that basically is the forward_command_controller, without the realtime buffers. It subscribes to a single Float64MultiArray commands topic.

For some reason, the controllers subscriber stops receiving topics after a few messages. This results in the commands not being updated and sent to the hardware.

I suspect that using asio in a thread inside the ros2_control architecture might be causing problems but I am not certain.

Fell free to ask for more information. Any help would be appreciated !

EDIT: I tested with a minimal example with and without asio running in a thread and the result is the same. The topics stop being received after some short time. So the issue seems unrelated to asio.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411534/ros2_control/asio-:-topics-stops-being-received/) by [Sam_Prt](https://answers.ros.org/users/108956/sam_prt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2023-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug related to issue [#656](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues/656) in rmw_fastrtps. See the issue I opened on [ros2_control/issues/923](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/923).

The bug is now fixed.

---

Originally posted by [Sam_Prt](https://answers.ros.org/users/108956/sam_prt/) with karma: 28 on 2023-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0